# Does Allah forgive disobeying and insulting parents even after punishment?

Tags: sin, punishment, forgiveness, tawba, parents

I‘m a 15 year-old boy and unfortunately, since my childhood, I have always been very aggressive and disrespectful to my mother and my father. A couple of months ago, I would always shout at my parents and insult them whenever they shouted at me for doing something wrong. When I was very angry and sad, I would even hit my mother or try to curse my parents by making bad dua. My parents have always told me that it is a great sin to be disrespectful to parents but for some reason I just didn't care until now, having read that it is a major sin to disobey one’s parents. Especially when my parents had arguments (and they often do, my father even used to hit my mother and make her cry and she would always curse him) I was really angry with my parents.

However, I have always loved my parents and they have never been really disappointed with me for a long time. They would always forgive me for being rude to them. So in general, we do have a great relationship and we laugh a lot and are really happy together.
Now, since a couple of months I feel really bad and cursed by Allah,for I have a big health issue and I feel like or I do strongly believe that this is a punishment by God for disobeying my parents for years, insulting them, cursing them, even hitting them a couple of times.

And now I feel really bad and guilty and have already asked Allah as well as my parents for forgiveness and my parents say I have always been a very nice son, but I know that I should never have behaved like that.  Lately, I have been really frustrated and felt like being abandoned by Allah, wherefore I even started to become angry with God. But I know this is another major sin.

Will Allah forgive me and cure my illness (even if it‘s theoretically uncurable) if my parents have forgiven me and if I keep asking Him for forgiveness? I feel very guilty and feel like having ruined my whole life just by being so rude to my parents and I regret it a lot. I try to do my best to respect my parents and stop being rude to them. Will the "curse" and punishment always last on me? I wish I had never insulted my parents this way, making Allah angry... I know Allah is very forgiving, but I think my sins were far too big to be forgiven.

Comment: Allah forgives all sins. No sin is too big for Allah to forgive. If you don’t turn to Allah and give into Satan making you think your sins are too much or too bad, then you’ve lost. The battle is not being perfect, it’s coming back to Allah over and over and over again.

Comment: Thank you very much. You‘re right, Allah forgives all sins. But does he also let go of punishment if the sins are forgiven?

Comment: Yes. There’s no need to punish over something He’s already forgiven. However, in your case, there’s a catch. Allah also says that if you’ve hurt someone, you must apologize to them. If they don’t forgive you, he won’t forgive you. So ask your parents for forgiveness and then repent.

Comment: Alhamdullilah I‘ve asked my parents for forgiveness and they have forgiven me. They told me that they are absolutely happy with me as their son and they don‘t blame me for anything. But I mean the punishment is already there? Will it go away if the sins are forgiven?

Comment: What punishment?

Comment: An illness and I‘m quite sure it‘s happened because of my sins.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will Allah forgive me for doing X ? (reference question)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/71337/will-allah-forgive-me-for-doing-x-reference-question)

Answer (score 0):

Does God forgive disobedience and insult to parents even after punishment?
Every sin can be repented, and God Himself has said: “Allah forgives all sins; God forgives all sins. ”True repentance is the same as repentance; It means repentance and remorse without return. If one feels that he has truly repented of his past and changed his path to God, he should know that he is a true repentant and such repentance will never be rejected.
Allameh Majlisi writes in the description of the book Usul Kafi about the meaning of parental separation: Disobey things that are not forbidden by the Shari'a and reason; What is more, it is stated in the statement of Imam Sadegh (as) that the least ungratefulness of parents is saying "O". "Taking a hard look at parents, grieving them and leaving certain responsibilities to them, such as not meeting the financial needs of parents if necessary, have also been reported as cases of children being separated."
Some sins, such as disrespecting parents, are not only forgiven through repentance, but also through parental consent.

- The first stage (satisfaction)
  In order to satisfy them, the first thing you need to do is ask them for permission, even if you can, kiss their hands and ask them to make you lawful, repeat this several times, they will surely agree. See what they like, for example, your mother is interested in a particular dress, take it as a gift, or, for example, your father is interested in going on a trip, provide travel facilities for him. Make sure they are satisfied soon.
- The second stage (performing child duties)
  But after they are satisfied, you should also pay attention to the following matters and observe these issues in relation to them. Duties and responsibilities of the children (taken from Surah Isra ', verses 23 and 24):

1. Obedience and obedience to parents.
2. Kindness and benevolence and service to parents. Do as much as you can for them and do not get tired of it at all.
3. Do not say annoying words to your parents.
4. Do not yell at your parents (but speak kindly to them).
5. To bring down the wings of humility for parents.
6. Meet the needs of parents as much as possible.
7. Maintain parental respect, as mentioned below:
   A) Do not stretch his legs in front of his parents.
   B) Give them gifts on different occasions such as Mother's Day or Father's Day.
   J . Avoid misplaced jokes and ugly words in front of them.
   D. Pray for them and for their health.
   H.. Help them with household chores.

Ref: https://www.porseman.com/article/%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%A8%D9%87-%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%82-%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF%DB%8C%D9%86/35894
[My father is forcing me to wear the hijab](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/69376/my-father-is-forcing-me-to-wear-the-hijab)

Answer (score 0):

You can always repent Allah said "What! do you think that you will be left alone while Allah has not yet known those of you who have struggled hard and have not taken any one as an adherent besides Allah and His Apostle and the believers; and Allah is aware of what you do."

In another aya in the quran he said "Does man reckon that he will be left in vain?"

And in another meaning "Does a person think that he will be left alone without purpose."

And Allah always says That he will never leave his obeyers alone.

You can always repent as long as your parents forgive you Allah inshallah will forgive you

All sins can be forgiven so don't be sad "O my Servants who have transgressed against their souls! Despair not of the Mercy of Allah: for Allah forgives all sins: for He is Forgiving, Most Merciful."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).